# Write query for search functionality in C#/ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to include a search functionality in a ASP.NET Web Application using a search textbox. I have a controller (HomeController) which include an Index (list all data) and a Search (based on user input) Action Method but I'm having trouble writing the code/query for the Search Action Method. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
//textbox from the View
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))
                    {

                        @Html.Editor("SearchBox")

                        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                    }

//The model

public class EventViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }

        public TimeSpan? Duration { get; set; }

        public string Author { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }

        public static Expression<Func<Event, EventViewModel>> ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return e => new EventViewModel()
                {
                    Id = e.Id,
                    Title = e.Title,
                    StartDateTime = e.StartDateTime,
                    Duration = e.Duration,
                    Location = e.Location,
                    Author = e.Author.FullName
                };
            }
        }
    }



public class UpcomingPassedEventsViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<EventViewModel> UpcomingEvents { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<EventViewModel> PassedEvents { get; set; }
    }

//controller


public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var events = this.db.Events
                .OrderBy(e => e.StartDateTime)
                .Where(e => e.IsPublic)
                .Select(EventViewModel.ViewModel);

            var upcomingEvents = events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime > DateTime.Now);
            var passedEvents = events.Where(e => e.StartDateTime <= DateTime.Now);
            return View(new UpcomingPassedEventsViewModel()
            {
                UpcomingEvents = upcomingEvents,
                PassedEvents = passedEvents
            });
        }

public ActionResult Search(string SearchBox)
        {



        }
```

Comment: What is the trouble you are having with "writing the code/query for the Search Action Method."? Can't you use the same code as in the `Index()` action but just change `.Where(e => e.IsPublic)` to `.Where(e => e.IsPublic && e.Title == SearchBox)` assuming you have a `Title` property in your `Event` entity.

Comment: @Hadi - It works! Thanks for your reply

Comment: You have to say thanks to @granit he is the one who commented. I only formatted your code